# Recusively find a file in whole system, return first folder

Tags: c#, .net, file

I'm trying to make a recursive function to return the first folder where the file is found.

I don't use `GetFiles` because the function stop when there is an exception.

However, it always stops at the 2nd folder and don't return anything cause the file is not found. What am I doing wrong ?

```
    private static bool IsDirFound = false;
    private static string SearchFile(string directory)
    {
        var fileFound = Directory.GetFiles(directory).FirstOrDefault(f => f.EndsWith("file.exe"));
        if (fileFound != null)
        {
            IsDirFound = true;
            return directory;
        }
        else if (!IsDirFound)
        {
            foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(subDir);
                    return SearchFile(subDir); // it always stop a the 2nd folder
                }
                catch
                {
                    // swallow
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Not using the debugger to step through the code to find the error?

Comment: as I said... my recursivity stops at the 2nd folder

Comment: Doing Wrong: 1. not catching exception. "swallow" ..ahem. 2. no logging, try `Trace.TraceInformation(subDir);` 3. Debug, debug debug.

Comment: There is likely an `AccessViolation` -- are you running as a local administrator account?

Comment: I'm catching exception because I don't want it to crash at first folder I can't access.
And yes i'm admin of the computer.

Comment: I would print fileFound to see it t is really null or just "". Or check for valid string to begin with.

Comment: @PL Audet you are calling the SearchFile function with return keyword in loop. So your function will not be called for all values of array. Your program will triverse only through first subdirectories.

Comment: @habib I tried, without using the `return` (only return if the value is found) but it returns nothing.

Comment: @PLAudet - Doing `catch { /* swallow */ }` is very bad. You should avoid exception catching unless you're catching specific exceptions that you can meaningfully handle.

Comment: @Enigmativity What can I do then, so this code doesnt crash when it encounter a folder I don't have access to, and I don't care when it happens?

Comment: @PLAudet - You should catch the specific exception that is raised when you don't have permission for the folder. The rule is only ever catch specific exceptions that you can meaningfully handle. Better yet, it would be be better to test that you have permission first before try to access the folder. Catching exceptions can severely slow down your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity Well I knew I was slowing my code down, but since it was for a really small project I didn't care. However I will try to look for a way to test If I have access to folder, instead of swallowing the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with recursive methods, its easy to cause a a stackoverflow exception

Here is your problem

```
else if (!IsDirFound) // When found
{
   ...
}
return null; // you return false
```

However i tweaked this to be a bit more powerful, obviously you'll get better performance without the Func however it is more usable.. I'll leave these details up to you.

**Example**

```
private static string SearchFile(string directory, Func<string, bool> condition)
{
   // get all files
   var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);

   // check the file against what you want
   if (files.Any(condition.Invoke))
      return directory; // if its found return

   // get all dirs
   var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);

   // check each one
   foreach (var dir in dirs)
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"Searching {dir}");

      try
      {
         // recurse
         var result = SearchFile(dir, condition);

         // if its found return
         if (result != null)
            return result;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         // log
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }
   }
   // nothing found here bail
   return null;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var result = SearchFile(@"D:\", file => file.EndsWith("test.blah") );
```

Comment: @Mhd his mistake was   else if (!IsDirFound), when it was found it returns null, which whips it out

Comment: @Mhd I was alwatys returning the recursivity instead of doing it only if I found something.